# Однородные или неоднородные определения в этом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-неоднородные-определения

Предложение из тестового задания, и ответ на него не совсем очевиден:

*Воздух дрожал от **непрерывного(,) многоголосого** рева толпы.*

Можно ли здесь поставить запятую? Нужно ли здесь ставить запятую? От чего конкретно это зависит?

Comment: Здесь явно неоднородные. Эта тема долго была в числе тех немногих, в которых не разобрался (как-то она не давалась). Но теперь её хорошо понимаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как мне кажется, для тестов ответ является как раз очевидным: определения неоднородны, запятая не ставится.

***Непрерывный*** и ***многоголосый*** не характеризуют ***рёв*** с одной стороны, не создают синонимических отношений, не объединены причинно-следственной связью, не представляют собой "художественные определения" и пр.

> Неоднородные определения характеризуют предмет с разных сторон, в разных отношениях, т. е. выражают признаки, относящиеся к разным родовым (общим) понятиям: <...> *Мы жили в подвале **большого каменного** дома* (М. Г.) — размер и материал <...>
> Если такие признаки объединены общим родовым понятием, подобные определения могут стать однородными: *Для туристской базы отведён **большой, каменный** дом* (объединяющий признак — ‘благоустроенный’).

Разве что "сходство производимого ими впечатления" (с большой натяжкой) может сблизить эти определения и отнести к однородным – не знаю...

[**Однородные и неоднородные определения**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=98) (Розенталь)

P. S. Sharon, а как вы думаете, *многоголосый рёв толпы* – приемлемое сочетание? Толпа вроде не может одним голосом кричать, петь, реветь...

Comment: Два примера из Нацкорпуса: 1) *...попал, собака, ― кричала вся толпа в один голос*. 2) *- Нет, что ты, батюшка! - отмахиваясь руками, в один голос откликнулась толпа*. Так что я полагаю, что "многоголосый рёв толпы" -- это всё-таки не плеоназм. Кто был в галдящей толпе, тот знает, что это довольно меткое описание, хоть и уже заштампованное.

Comment: Если посмотреть в словаре, то слово многозначное, а общий его смысл - это то, что воспринимается как очень громкий звук, сильный шум. Он может  казаться единым, согласным в чем-то, а может обозначать разные настроения.

Comment: @Nektoid   "многоголосый рёв толпы", да, для меня это нормально звучит. А вот "в один голос" – это не совсем то, это "разом".

Comment: Пароход шел, а вслед ему несся этот единый многоголосый вой. [Виктор Розов. Удивление перед жизнью (1960-2000)]

Comment: Посмотрела ответ в оригинале: https://www.litmir.me/br/?b=3107&p=13  Не переставая, гремели оркестры.Воздух дрожал от непрерывного многоголосого рева толпы. Улицы оглушительно стонали, гудела мостовая, в окнах жалко звякали стекла.  Так что вы оказались правы...

Comment: @Sharon Ага, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что тестовое задание не рассчитано на углубление в различные писательские вольности, исключения, авторскую пунктуацию и проч., поэтому с точки зрения теста ответ очевиден: запятая не нужна, определения не однородны.

Но притянуть за уши к однородности можно:

> [Запятая ставится,] если в условиях контекста, характеризуя предмет с
> разных сторон, объединяются каким-либо общим признаком (внешним видом,
> сходством производимого ими впечатления, отнесением к отдаленному
> общему понятию, причинно-следственной связью и т. д.): ...*Раздался
> страшный, оглушительный удар грома* (‘страшный, потому что
> оглушительный’); *Наступили тяжёлые, мрачные времена* (‘тяжелые,
> поэтому и мрачные’); *Он прикрыл глаза красными, воспалёнными веками*
> (‘красными, потому что воспаленными’).

*Непрерывный*, потому что *многоголосый*, why not.

Comment: Нет, why not не подойдет. Толпа может и замолчать на какое-то время, если ее чем-то очень удивить...))

Comment: @Sharon нет, вы не поняли. Одноголосый рёв (если речь про живое существо) не может быть непрерывным, потому что существу надо брать дыхание. А здесь (предположим) говорится: рёв был непрерывный, потому что во много голосов (то есть когда кто-то брал дыхание, другие продолжали реветь). Цепное дыхание, как это называется в хоровом деле.

Comment: Но у нас-то другая тема (толпа),  а там причинно-следственной связи нет (вот и Александр об этом говорит) толпа может кричать непрерывно, а может замолкать. Здесь сближение возможно на каком-то общем впечатлении, а вот на каком?

Answer (score 1):

**1. О тестовом вопросе**

Там были приведены 4 варианта, и нужно было отметить предложения с неоднородными определениями. В двух из них определения были точно неоднородными, в третьем – однозначно однородное, а это было четвертое. Вот и непонятно, сколько ошибок надо было найти: две или одну?

**2. О литературе**

В Нацкорпусе есть примеры, где подобные определения оформлены как однородные. А вот в заданном предложении как определить наилучший вариант?  Ведь для конкретного предложения только одно решение является наиболее подходящим. И можно ли его так изменить, чтобы решение было однозначным?

**Примеры:**

…он неловко повернул голову, **многоголосый, гулкий рев** толпы бился в узорчатом, стрельчатом окне; [П. Л. Проскурин. Судьба. Книга вторая. Не отринь (1993)]

… **Глухой, многоголосый гул** толпы проник снаружи под своды зала. [А. Н. Толстой. Аэлита. (Закат Марса.) (1939)]

― догоняя грохот, невнятно донесся из глубины оврага **многоголосый, встревоженный вопль**. [Михаил Ковлев. Машина и сердце // Всемирный следопыт, 1930]

**Грубый, многоголосый, обрывающийся звонкой лавиной вал** голосов заглушил его. [Ф. Д. Крюков. Шквал // «Русское Богатство», 1909]

Comment: Мне попались тесты, где нужно выбрать только один вариант с одной запятой. Так вот это предложение, по мнению составителей, должно быть без запятой.  А как оно в книге автора, Григория Белых, не ищется, выдает только тесты. // Примеры у вас хорошие, что-то объединяющее в определениях всё-таки есть. Может, и в нашем случае есть: если бы рёв был прерывистым, воздух вздрагивал бы, а не дрожал... Ну а составителям нужно скрупулёзнее относиться к примерам.

Comment: О, оно есть в Нацкорпусе без запятой.

Comment: Ну вот, там хороший ответ, со ссылкой на автора, и тоже говорится о сближении по общему впечатлению. Поэтому выбор, как говорится, за автором: видит ли он общий признак, хочет ли он монотонности и перечислительной интонации.

Comment: Ну, для уровня mail.ru, может, и хороший.  Как вам отвечающий? Чем-то на меня похож. Но не карьерист, до Высшего разума ему еще далеко.

Comment: А!!! Так это вы? Я даже не посмотрел на имя, статус и время ответа. :))

Comment: Нет, не я, это мой двойник. А вы тоже, оказывается, не всегда внимательны. А я-то вас считала идеальным представителем Homo sapiens.

Comment: Я в ответы mail.ru  захожу о-очень редко. По вашей ссылке по-быстрому прочитал, да и обратно.